# Core data creates keeps populating with default values and doesn't save on close

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am fairly new to core data. I am trying to make a form where each time I add a section header and text from a sheet view, it appears within a new section. The problem I am having is every time I open the sheet view to enter the section header and text saved via core data, a big list of my default values of List Name and List Section appears on the main screen upon dismissing the sheet view. They also disappear after a relaunch so I don't think I am saving the data correctly.

[image]

I currently have the core data entity of `Lists` with the attributes of `listName` and `listSection` which are used in my form as seen in the image.

```
struct ContentView: View {
 @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
 @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var lists: FetchedResults<Lists>

var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form() {
                ForEach(lists) { list in
                    Section(header: Text(list.listSection ?? "List Section")) {
                        NavigationLink {
                            Text("Next Page")
                        } label: {
                            Text(list.listName ?? "List Name")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
      }
}
```

I create this data via a sheet view. I also use the var dismiss to hide the sheet view, bringing me back to my main view code shown above.

```
struct AddList: View { 
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
   
    @State private var listNameEntry: String = ""
    @State private var listSectionEntry: String = ""
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var lists: FetchedResults<Lists>
    
    var body: some View {
        let list = Lists(context: moc) //used to save to core data

            Form {
                Section() {
                    TextField("List Name", text: $listNameEntry) {
                        list.listName = listNameEntry
                    }
                    TextField("List Section", text: $listSectionEntry) {
                        list.listSection = listSectionEntry
                    }
                }
                Section() {
                    Button("Done") {
                        try? moc.save()
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: In your sheet, what is `list`? How is it declared, how it is initiated and how is the main view updated after the sheet is closed? Please update the question with this information

Comment: I have explained where list comes from in the updated question.

Comment: The line `let list = Lists(context: moc)` creates a new object in the database whenever the view is rendered (which can happen very often). Move it into the last section right before the save line and before saving copy the attributes. And it’s recommended to name entities in singular form.

Comment: If you want to use sections you should use a SectionedFetchRequest instead and there is no point in having a fetch request property in your second view